# Why should I structure my HTML emails with tables rather than divs?

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, gmail

I have been reading on many websites that the layout for a HTML email should be structured with tables rather than using divs. What is the reason for this?

Comment: Could you provide these links? I thought it was just otherwise.

Comment: Old thinking.  <div> and .css are the way to go, Unless the data really is tabular.

Comment: http://www.outlook-apps.com/html-ignored-by-outlook/ (at the bottom of the page)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935472/html-email-tables-or-divs

Comment: Sorry! I haven't read "emails".

Comment: http://templates.mailchimp.com/development/html/ Mail chimp also seems to suggest the use of tables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of lack of css compatibility with email clients listed at [Email Client CSS Support](http://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/email-client-css-support/). So your rules inside `style` gonna be ignored in Gmail for exemple, rather than table inline rules

Answer (score 1):

Since Outlook 2007 (on Windows) emails with HTML are rendered using Word. Word doesn't have very good support for HTML and CSS so that's why you're stuck with tables for layout.

[Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201(v=office.12).aspx)