# Gmail doesn't accept a full width email

Tags: html, css, email, gmail

I have a little problem with Gmail email template. It happens only in Gmail app, I want a full width email template, but on right side, margin is a bit bigger than left. I know, there is some padding from screen sides in app, but that right side, doesn't looks good. There is screenshot
[image]

And there is my HTML code

```
      <div style="width: 100%!important;background: #E4E2E5;background:-webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #fff 15%, #E4E2E5);background: linear-gradient(to top, #fff 15%, #E4E2E5);padding: 60px 0 0 0;margin: 0 0 200px 0;">
  <style>
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400');
        .container{width: 100%;max-width: 850px;}
        </style>
    <table style="font-family:'Roboto';background:white;" class="container">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent euismod consectetur pulvinar. Vivamus laoreet semper ante, quis iaculis dui fermentum vel. Integer at efficitur nibh. Morbi tempor convallis mauris, et cursus eros volutpat vitae. Nulla sodales nunc sit amet porttitor sollicitudin. Integer hendrerit, lectus vel sagittis elementum, leo nisi condimentum urna, ut tincidunt mauris augue sit amet leo. Sed a ultricies risus. Nam non condimentum est. Aliquam erat volutpat. Etiam placerat velit sit amet sagittis mattis. Cras blandit venenatis venenatis.
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: Try to avoid divs / classes. In this case you should just put the style of the div in your table. I'm not sure how your problem occurs. The reason could be that you're using a class. Just put the styles in the table style="". Could you try this and let us know? Then I'll give it a try myself if I find some time today.

Comment: @JeroenE still the same problem :(

Comment: let the tr content be like `<tr><td><p> content here </p></td></tr>`

Comment: @AshishSrivastava still not the solution

Comment: @DanielsJirgensons But you still should change that (what Ashish said). Bad syntax the way you've written your code right now.

Comment: Do you have negative values for padding? Gmail ignores margin and padding properties if they have a negative value. Also hope [this](https://litmus.com/community/discussions/1281-100-width-sections-don-t-work-properly-in-gmail-app) is helpful for you.:)

Comment: @JeroenE I edited like this, but still, without changes

Comment: @AshishSrivastava do you see any negative values!?

Comment: I maybe found your answer on Stack: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25630139/100-width-tables-dont-work-in-gmail-android . Force the width (!important) to set it to 100%. Make sure to do this in-line! So: style="width:100%!important;"